# Using GDAL in Python to Convert NetCDF to ASCII and flip latitudes

Tags: python, gdal, netcdf

I have a NetCDF file containing bathymetry. I am using the GDAL and NETCDF4 libraries to export the file to ESRI ASCII using the 'AAIGrid' format. However, a common problem is the latitudes are in the reverse order (see [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/2654) for patch made to gdal and [here](https://www.chadagreene.com/CDT/tutorial_netcdf.html) for Matlab and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700254/the-variable-from-a-netcdf-file-comes-out-flipped) for R solutions).

I think the solution can be achieved using Numpy and flipud function. I am not sure whether to flip the bathymetry or the latitude. When plotting using matplotlib, both seem to work to fix the problem.

I seem to be encountering two problems. First, when using gdal.Translate, the output Dataset cannot be passed as the NetCDF4 'Dataset' object - it must be a file. I would like to pass it a Dataset object which I have modified by flipping the latitudes. When I pass in an object (even an unmodified Dataset object which just references the original .nc file), I get the following error:

```
#gdal.Translate("out.txt", "test4.nc", format="AAIGrid", noData="-10")
gdal.Translate("out.txt", new_netcdf, format="AAIGrid", noData="-10")

    TypeError: in method 'TranslateInternal', argument 2 of type 'GDALDatasetShadow *'
```

Second, I cannot seem to flip the latitudes by modifying the original file.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np

file = "ORIGINAL\Bathymetry_1km.nc"
netcdf_f = Dataset(file, "r", format="NETCDF4")

latitudes = netcdf_f.variables['lat']
lat_flipped = np.flipud(latitudes)
netcdf_f.variables['lat'][:] = lat_flipped

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-457cda137417> in <module>
----> 1 netcdf_f.variables['lat'][:] = lat_flipped
netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable.__setitem__()
netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4.Variable._put()
netCDF4\_netCDF4.pyx in netCDF4._netCDF4._ensure_nc_success()
RuntimeError: NetCDF: HDF error
```

So, next I create a new NetCDF 'Dataset' object (actually as a file on the drive because I can't figure out an alternative) and populate it with the lats, lons, and bathy dimensions / variables from the original dataset. That seems to work except when I go to translate it to ASCII, I end up with a grid full of 9.9692099683868690468e+36 and nothing else.

Comment: flipped in what way?

Answer (score -1):

Esri ArcGIS can read netCDF files directly. No need to convert to ascii.

Comment: I'm not reading the ASCII files into ArcGIS